# Typescript: for (let key in obj), `key` is `Extract<keyof T, string>` instead of just `keyof T`, why?

Tags: typescript, for-loop, generics, extract, keyof

I want to `iterate` over an `object`, when I use `for-in`, I notice a very weird thing:

```js
function forIn<T extends object>(obj: T): void {
  for (let key in obj) {
    // key's type is `Extract<keyof T, string>` instead of just `keyof T`
  }
}
```

My VSCode screenshot:

[image]

This leads me two questions:

1. Why `key`'s type is `Extract<keyof T, string>` instead of just `keyof T`?
2. Object's `key`s are always string type, so `Extract<keyof T, string>` does totally nothing, right?

Comment: TypeScript 2.9 [expanded](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types) key types to include `number` and `symbol` types also.

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 2.9 expanded key types to include number and symbol types also.